# PHPUnit : Assert a parameter when pass it to mock object

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

For the code below,

```
$mockObject->expects($this->at(0))
           ->method('search')
           ->with($searchConfig)
           ->will($this->returnValue([]));
```

This line will automatic make a assertensure that when it call method `search` it must contain `$searchConfig` parameters. In this case, we have to provide totally matched `$searchConfig` but sometime it is hard if it is an array or an object.

Are there any possible way to let PHPUnit call to some specific method to assert that it contains arguments pass in a method as we want?

For example, I may create closure function to assert as below instead of using `->with()` method

```
function ($config){
    $this->assertFalse(isset($config['shouldnothere']));
    $this->assertTrue($config['object']->isValidValue());
}
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use `->with($this->callback())` and pass in a closure to perform more complex assertions on the argument.

From the [PHPUnit Docs](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.examples.SubjectTest.php)

> The callback() constraint can be used for more complex argument
>   verification. This constraint takes a PHP callback as its only
>   argument. The PHP callback will receive the argument to be verified as
>   its only argument and should return TRUE if the argument passes
>   verification and FALSE otherwise.
>
> Example 10.13: More complex argument verification
>
> getMock('Observer', array('reportError'));
>
> ```
>     $observer->expects($this->once())
>              ->method('reportError')
>              ->with($this->greaterThan(0),
>                     $this->stringContains('Something'),
>                     $this->callback(function($subject){
>                       return is_callable(array($subject, 'getName')) &&
>                              $subject->getName() == 'My subject';
>                     }));
>
>     $subject = new Subject('My subject');
>     $subject->attach($observer);
>
>     // The doSomethingBad() method should report an error to the observer
>     // via the reportError() method
>     $subject->doSomethingBad();
> } } ?>
> ```

So your test would become:

```
$mockObject->expects($this->at(0))
->method('search')
->with($this->callback(
    function ($config){
        if(!isset($config['shouldnothere']) && $config['object']->isValidValue()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    })
->will($this->returnValue([]));
```

Comment: I always forget to use `return true` when validating multiple arguments.

Comment: Btw, if your function has more then 1 argument, then the this->callback() only applies for the first argument. So you need to define a callback for each argument

Comment: Thanks for this, that on had me scratching my head for a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Mockery for it

Say I have a code

```
$productValidator = app(ProductValidator:class)->setProduct($productIn);
```

That would be the test code

```
use Mockery;

...

    $productValidator            
        ->shouldReceive('setProduct')->once()
        ->with(Mockery::type(Product::class))
        ->with(Mockery::on(function($productIn) use ($productId) {
                return $productIn->id === $productId;
            }))
        ->andReturn($productValidator);
```

Tested on phpunit "version": "8.5.8"

Comment: $this->callback() was not working for me in a Laravel 10 project. This response worked for me.