# Php-unit - Failed asserting that 'myDomain\Entity\Likes' is an instance of class "myDomain\Entity\Likes"

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm making tests for an web application, it removes a Likes Record from database, but I'm getting this ambiguous fail.

> Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked 1 time(s).
>   Parameter 0 for invocation myMelomanBundle\Repository\LikesRepository::remove('myDomain\Entity\Likes') does not match expected value.
>   Failed asserting that 'myDomain\Entity\Likes' is an instance of class "myDomain\Entity\Likes".

DislikePublicationUseCaseTest.php

```
    <?php

    namespace myMelomanBundle\Likes;


    class DislikePublicationUseCaseTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
    const User = 2;
    const PUB = 15;
    /**
     * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    private $publicationRepositoryMock;
    /**
     * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    private $userRepositoryMock;
    /**
     * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    private $likesRepositoryMock;
    /**
     * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    private $entityManagerMock;

    /**
     * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    private $userMock;

    /**
     * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    private $publicationMock;

    private $likesMock;

    /**
     * @var DislikePublicationUseCase
     */
    private $dislikePublicationUseCase;

    /**
     * @var LikeDTO
     */
    private $likeDTO;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->publicationRepositoryMock = $this-
>createMock(PublicationRepository::class);
        $this->userRepositoryMock = $this-
>createMock(UserRepository::class);
        $this->likesRepositoryMock = $this-
>createMock(LikesRepository::class);
        $this->entityManagerMock = $this-
>createMock(EntityManager::class);
        $this->userMock = $this->createMock(User::class);
        $this->publicationMock = $this->createMock(Publication::class);
        $this->likesMock = $this->createMock(Likes::class);
        $this->likeDTO = new LikeDTO(self::User, self::PUB);
        $this->dislikePublicationUseCase = new DislikePublicationUseCase(
            $this->publicationRepositoryMock,
            $this->userRepositoryMock,
            $this->likesRepositoryMock,
            $this->entityManagerMock
        );
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        $this->publicationRepositoryMock = null;
        $this->userRepositoryMock = null;
        $this->likesRepositoryMock = null;
        $this->entityManagerMock = null;
        $this->userMock = null;
        $this->publicationMock = null;
        $this->likesMock = null;
    }

    /** @test */
    public function dummyTest()
    {
        $this->dislikePublicationUseCase;
    }

    /** @test */
    public function shouldRemoveALikeOneTimeIfItExist()
    {
        $this->givenALikeRepositoryThatHasASpecificLike();
        $this->andGivenAUserRepositoryThatHaveASpecifiUser();
        $this->andGivenAPublicationRepositoryThatHaveASpecificPublication();
        $this->thenTheLikeShouldBeRemovedOnce();
        $this->whenTheDislikePublicationUseCaseIsExecutedWithASpecificParameters();
    }

    private function givenALikeRepositoryThatHasASpecificLike()
    {
        $this->likesRepositoryMock
            ->method('findOneBy')
            ->willReturn(Likes::class);
    }
    private function andGivenAUserRepositoryThatHaveASpecifiUser()
    {
        $this->userRepositoryMock
            ->method('find')
            ->willReturn($this->userMock);
    }

    private function andGivenAPublicationRepositoryThatHaveASpecificPublication()
    {
        $this->publicationRepositoryMock
            ->method('find')
            ->willReturn($this->publicationMock);
    }

    private function thenTheLikeShouldBeRemovedOnce()
    {
        $this->likesRepositoryMock
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('remove')
            ->with($this->isInstanceOf(Likes::class)); // Here Fails
    }

    private function 
    whenTheDislikePublicationUseCaseIsExecutedWithASpecificParameters()
    {
        $this->dislikePublicationUseCase->execute($this->likeDTO);
    }
}
```

DislikePublicationUseCase.php

```
 <?php

namespace myDomain\UseCases\Like;

class DislikePublicationUseCase
{
    private $publicationRepository;
    private $userRepository;
    private $likesRepository;
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct (
        PublicationRepositoryInterface $publicationRepository,
        UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository,
        LikesRepositoryInterface $likesRepository,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
    )
    {
        $this->publicationRepository    = $publicationRepository;
        $this->userRepository           = $userRepository;
        $this->likesRepository          = $likesRepository;
        $this->entityManager            = $entityManager;
    }

    public function execute(LikeDTO $likeDTO)
    {
        try {

            $user           = $this->userRepository->find($likeDTO->getUserId());
            $publication    = $this->publicationRepository->find($likeDTO->getPublicationId());

            $like = $this->likesRepository->findOneBy(
                array(
                    'user' => $user,
                    'publication' => $publication
                )
            );
            $this->likesRepository->remove($like);

            return true;

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Why it fails if it's the same entity? It's the entity that I'm expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to pass an instance of `Likes` as a parameter to `LikesRepository::remove()`. You're close, but you're trying to pass a `boolean` as a parameter instead.

So you need to pass it a `Likes` instance. You already have a mock of it, so pass it:

```
private function thenTheLikeShouldBeRemovedOnce()
{
    $this->likesRepositoryMock
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('remove')
        ->with($this->likesMock); // Here Fails
}
```

I don't know what `remove()`'s return value is, but you can test that too:

```
private function thenTheLikeShouldBeRemovedOnce()
{
    $this->likesRepositoryMock
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('remove')
        ->with($this->likesMock)
        ->will($this->returnValue(true)); // if remove() returns true on success
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @ishegg!  I was focusing on on the wrong method! Now it works! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Look closely at this method:

```
private function givenALikeRepositoryThatHasASpecificLike()
{
    $this->likesRepositoryMock
        ->method('findOneBy')
        ->willReturn(Likes::class);
}
```

Spotted it yet?

Spoiler:

```
->willReturn(Likes::class);
```

The mock will return the *string* Likes::class.

```
var_dump(Likes::class); // string(19) "myDomain\Entity\Likes"
```

Change it to something like:

```
private function givenALikeRepositoryThatHasASpecificLike()
{
    $this->likesRepositoryMock
        ->method('findOneBy')
        ->willReturn(new Likes());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$this->assertInstanceOf(Likes::class, $likes); accepted two argument class and object to asserts if instance of class expected object. And, you can use [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181038/phpunit-assert-a-parameter-when-pass-it-to-mock-object) function to asserts parameters passed to methods

Comment: First I was tried with no luck. Second does not work...Thanks

Comment: what is the error, if you use correctly $this->assertInstanceOf ?

Comment: Like this...->with($this->assertInstanceOf(Likes::class, $this->likesMock));
"Failed asserting that 'myDomain\Entity\Likes' matches expected null." Regards

Comment: try this
->with($this->callback(
    function ($like) {
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Likes::class, $like);
    }));

Comment: Same as the first one: Failed asserting that 'myDomain\Entity\Likes' is an instance of class "myDomain\Entity\Likes".

Comment: what about this 
 ->with($this->callback( function ($like) { 
\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::assertInstanceOf(Likes::class, $like); }));